# Building php-devel package from source (php 5.3)

Tags: php, php53, rpm

I am building PHP 5.3 rpm packages for our custom CentOS 5 yum repo. I am fairly new to building rpms to be honest, but I have had moderate success downloading the SRPMS for a given package and repackaging them using "rpmbuild --rebuild" command.

One thing that is throwing me off though is how to satisfy the php-devel package.. I obviously have the PHP 5.3 source files as I was able to build my php-common and other packages with it.  But I am not sure how to actually build the devel package!  From what I understand, I already have most of what I need - the latest php 5.3.5 source tarball.  However I am not sure how to build the correct .spec file to satisfy what I need.

If you are knowledgeable in this area, would you mind helping a fellow sysadmin out?  Sharing a spec file or at least giving me some pointers on how to approach it.

Thanks much serverfault community!
-BajaBob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using this build of php53? http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/x86_64/RPMS/php53/

Comment: Actually no, I somehow missed that when I was scouring the testing channel. It will be quite helpful to use these vs rolling my own. I will give these a shot - however for the sake of this question it would be nice to know how that php-devel package is actually built!

Comment: This helped me out a bit, but still doesn't satisfy the needs of my developers.  While they do have a few of the php 5.3 packages in this repo, I am still having to roll my own for things like php-pecl-memcache, php-xdebug, APC, pear, etc.  Any other ideas on how to compile a php-devel package from source?

Comment: php-devel is built at the same time php is. The spec file in http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/SRPMS/php53-5.3.3-1.el5.src.rpm will show you what files go in it. pear is part of the base php install. For additional php packages I'd rebuild a SRPM from EPEL (e.g., http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/SRPMS/repoview/letter_p.group.html ). If you don't see a needed package you should be able to adapt a spec file from a similar type (pecl, pear) of package.